# Updating Craft 3 from RC1 to RC7 throws ErrorException

Tags: error-message, craft3, updates, composer

I have two Craft CMS 3 websites using Vagrant/Homestead & VirtualBox as the local server. Both were on RC1, and when trying to update to RC7 I get this error:

```
yii\base\ErrorException: unlink(/home/vagrant/sites/craft-site/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/1d/1d7666988f766c26d98233e048a41c263069493e993709f9ed7989e8bdfcce48.php): Permission denied in /home/vagrant/sites/craft-site/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseFileHelper.php:347
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/sites/craft-site/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseFileHelper.php(347): ::unlink()
#1 /home/vagrant/sites/craft-site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/FileHelper.php(101): yii\helpers\BaseFileHelper::removeDirectory()
#2 /home/vagrant/sites/craft-site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/FileHelper.php(409): craft\helpers\FileHelper::removeDirectory()
#3 /home/vagrant/sites/craft-site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(544): craft\helpers\FileHelper::clearDirectory()
#4 /home/vagrant/sites/craft-site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(165): craft\web\Application->_processUpdateLogic()
#5 /home/vagrant/sites/craft-site/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest()
#6 /home/vagrant/sites/craft-site/web/index.php(21): craft\web\Application->run()
#7 {main}
```

The same error happens whether I update through the admin or through composer. It happened to both of my sites as well.

I'm still learning development with Craft and PHP, but is this error telling me that I don't have permission rights to remove these files or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, it definitely looks like a permissions issue to me. I'd recommend checking out https://nystudio107.com/blog/hardening-craft-cms-permissions and https://nystudio107.com/blog/local-development-with-vagrant-homestead for more info on permissions and Vagrant. It's possible installing vagrant-bindfs like Andrew mentioned in that second article could fix your problem. Try it and let me know what happens :)